# How to pass parameters inside a callbackfunction using DialogFlow fulfillments

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I have the following code:

```
router.post('/agent/fullfilments', cors(corsOptions), function(request, response) {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Hello', hello);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('Callback request - yes', callbackRequestYes);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

and I would like to pass few parameters on callbackRequestYes function.
I tried something like this but didnt work:

```
function callbackRequestYes(agent) {
  console.log( "phone number: " + request.body.queryResult.parameters.phoneNumber);
  agent.add(`we will call you soon...`);
}
```

How can I pass a phoneNumber into a callback function so I will be able to print it inside callbackRequestYes() function

EDIT:
How can I respond by detecting input action and not Intent name, because Intent Names sometimes people change them but not input.action?

Answer (score 0):

appereantly seems that the agent parameter passed has all the info with it, thus this is working:

```
function callbackRequestYes(agent) {
  console.log(agent.parameters);
  console.log( "phone number: " + agent.parameters.phoneNumber);
  agent.add(`we will call you soon...`);
}
```